# Файл с расширением .xsb

Tags: файлы

Попал ко мне в руки файл с расширением .xsb
Чем его можно открыть? Я так понимаю это отчет какой-то

Answer (score 0):

Решено.
XSB файл это справка о доходах госслужащих, открывается программой СПО «Справки БК»